# <ui:include> a custom component

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

I have a package with a taglib that consist of a few custom made component.

There is a component uses icefaces "Panel Popup", which I created to do multiple-value look-up and to be used across multiple project.

I have been trying to use `<ui:include>` to attach it to other popup bean and rendered when required.

But  it just won't work. I even uses

`<namespace:Component> <namespace:Component>`, the page runs properly but just won't render 
the component when I click a button to make it visible.

The component works properly when I use  `<ui:include src="url link"/>`, but I do not want the component to exist in every project, I want to share it using a package.

May I know if there is other solution?

Thanks in advance
Caveman programmer!

Comment: Please post some code for us to look at.

Comment: I can't, the codes are in a cave :( I basically work in a cave for 10 hours before I come down the mountain to civilization every day. Any help and hint will help a lot.

Comment: You work in a cave? That is fascinating.... could you eleaborate on where you and what you are working on??

Comment: You're almost guaranteed to get no help then.

Comment: @gbtimmon you will be amaze by how many software engineer are made to work in depressing condition. Example providing a P4 CPU to work on ARCGIS with no internet. currently I work in a "cave" like environment where there are no internet connection or any possible help when you are there.

Comment: Seriously? Anyway.. You could just put code on an USB stick.. Based on the symptoms, I think I can see/guess the cause of this problem. Before posting an answer, can you please tell if you're using JSF 1.x or 2.x so that I can target the code examples on that?

Comment: 1.2 and NO USB STICK allowed.